# Paypal : Get a response of "txn_type= recurring payment " instead of "txn_type= recurring_payment_profile_created" for the first Time

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I used to implement paypal recurring payment into my web application.where I got a response from paypal through Instant payment Notification to my (paypalipn.php) page as follows,

```
$payment_status = completed;
                $txn_type = recurring_payment;
                $paypal_txn_id = id comes here;
                $parent_txn_id =  id comes here;
                $recurring_payment_id =  id comes here;
```

This response I got for first time but It is expected that for first time as,

```
$payment_status = completed;
                $txn_type = recurring_payment_profile_created;
                $paypal_txn_id = id comes here;
                $parent_txn_id =  id comes here;
                $recurring_payment_id =  id comes here;
```

so  any one point me what error may be occured or what may be the reason for this ........

Comment: I don't see what the problem is? Both events are fired when a new profile has been set up?

Answer (score 1):

Both events are typically fired when a new recurring payments profile is created.  One is for the creation of the recurring payments profile, and the other is for the first payment processed against that recurring payment profile.  Technically, `recurring_payment_profile_created` should come before `recurring_payment`; however, IPN is asynchronous, so the IPNs could be delivered out of order.